# Play Framework 2.4 binding form error

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

I have problems with form binding from request. I have the class Account that represents system user and the class Group to which this user belongs.

Account class

```
public class Account extends Model {

@Id
@Email
public String email;

@Required
@NotNull
public String password;

@Required
@NotNull
public String firstName;

@Required
@NotNull
public String lastName;

@Required
public String phone;

public MyRole role;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Group group;
```

Group class

```
public class Group extends Model {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Required
public Long id;

@Required
@NotNull
public String name;

@Required
@NotNull
public String description;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to insert a new user into the database. Html form contains all fields of the class Account and the combobox with all groups. How can I do it?
In html form div with groups

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="group.id">
       @for(group <- groups) {
            <option value="@group.id">@group.name</option>
       }
    </select>
</div>
```

Now I`m using this case

```
Form<Account> accountForm = form(Account.class).bindFromRequest();
Account account = accountForm.get();
account.group = Group.findGroupById(Long.valueOf(Form.form().bindFromRequest().get("group.id")));
```

But I think that this option is not very good.
How can I insert a user with a certain select group in one form?

Comment: What do you mean by _this options is not very good_? Is it not working or are you looking for a better approach?

Comment: bindFromRequest(Class<?> group)
I think you're looking something like this.
Or there is another option: 
bindFromRequest(String.. fields) which allows you to check only those fields which you want.

Comment: @Anton - It works, but I am looking for a better option.

Comment: Did you look into custom DataBinders? Maybe create one for Group and in the parse method hit the database with the id to retrieve the actual Group.